# Azure linux load balance with neo4j

Tags: azure, neo4j, load-balancing

I have 3 machines running Linux. I set the load balance, but only the first set of machine availability responds to requests.

When we turn off the first machine, the other two do not respond to external requests.

I do not have configured iptables on Linux and no restrictive. Does anyone know if there are limitations in Windows Azure as to load balance using Vms linux?

hugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure the load balancer correctly? You have to go to each instance and add the port for the load balancer.

I've successfully setup Neo4j with HAProxy in the past so I can guarantee that it works on Azure. In the end, the scenario you describe is pretty simple and straight forward and it should work out of the box if done properly. I suspect a misconfiguration.

Comment: I believe so Panagiotis, the three machines are within the same set of availability and there is only one external point. Looks like they are the endpoints: http://snag.gy/hbTJW.jpg

Comment: Is Neo4j configured to be HA? If yes, what is the minimum nodes you have set for a Quorum? I know that Neo4J stops responding if there is no quorum (that changed somewhere in v 2.0.6 (?) if I remember correctly), so even if the load balancer thinks that Neo4J is running, Neo4j won't reply to any requests.

The configuration on the endpoints seems right.

Comment: The problem was in the Neo4j configuration. When the updated version of the database, configuration files have changed and blocked external access.

Thank you for your help.